# How to make sure that android view did full layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-view

I am calling *inputView.draw(drawCanvas)* in order to save my view to bitmap.

```
  Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewWidth, viewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas drawCanvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
  inputView.draw(drawCanvas);
```

The bitmap does not contain complete view image (my view has custom drawing on canvas- pie chart with legend). The saved bitmap has just part of legend.

Reading javadoc of [View.draw(android.graphics.Canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas))

> The view must have already done a full layout before this function is called.

How to be sure that view did full layout?
When calling inputView.draw(drawCanvas) my view is rendered and visible on the screen.

Comment: Instead of editing the title as "answered", accept your own answer.. I guess you would need to wait for 24 hours to self accept.

Comment: will accept my answer, but have to wait *two* days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding following code

```
 int measuredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(viewWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
 int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(viewHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
 inputView.measure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
 inputView.layout(0, 0, inputView.getMeasuredWidth(), inputView.getMeasuredHeight());
```

before drawing to my bitmap.

What is strange, everything worked fine in two of three screens that I have. Saved bitmap was always complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check with Layout params.

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = layout.getLayoutParams();
```

Then check if is it full (I don't understand what do you mean with "full").

Comment: I am also unsure what 'the view must have already done a full layout' means. That is quote from javadoc of View.draw(Canvas). I have provided link.
I checked proposed code, and returend layoutParams  object is not null, and it is populated. Layout is definetly done before I try to save bitmap- object is visible on the screen (I call save from context menu). Also, before saving I call view.getWidth()/getHeight to obtain size of my bitmap, and that works fine.